# Count(*) в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть запрос, который выводит конкурсы:

```
SELECT `id`,`title` FROM `contests` WHERE `date`>NOW() LIMIT 20;
```

Мне нужно подсчитать сколько всего в базе конкурсов удовлетворяющих условию

```
WHERE `date`>NOW();
```

Я пробовал писать так, но не работает

```
SELECT COUNT(*),`id`,`title` FROM `contests` WHERE `date`>NOW() LIMIT 20;
```

Можно ли это сделать как-нибудь одним запросом (т.е. выбрать конкурсы и узнать количество в их в базе). НЕ прибегая к

```
select count(*) from `contests` where `date`>NOW();
```

Comment: Отделяйте текст от кода!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в любом случае придется делать два запроса. но если вам необходимо делать limit то грамотней их построить так:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from contests where `date`>NOW() limit 20;
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

в этом случае второй запрос вернет количество строк которое было бы выбрано без limit 20

[подробней](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подсказку, думаю так и сделаю!

Answer (score 0):

Делайте два запроса.

Comment: а как же поизвращаться? ) что то мне подсказывает что решение есть, надо немножко подумать.

Comment: Просто получается что таблица большая, и будет очень много WHERE, поэтому не хотелось бы, чтобы mysql пробегал два раза по одним и тем же колонкам.

Comment: Делайте два запроса. Будет быстрее.